# Error during training using Tensorflow with our own data

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, nltk

I am using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) for training for developing the model to detect whether the message is spam or not. I am using **Python**.

My training data size is 3000 rows and 3 columns, and the size of test data is 2700 rows and 3 columns.

```
Batch size: 500

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500

n_classes = 2

batch_size = 32
total_batches = int(3000 / batch_size)
hm_epochs = 10

x = tf.placeholder('float')
y = tf.placeholder('float')

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl1,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3000, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl2,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

output_layer = {'f_fum': None,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_classes])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])), }
```

I am getting this error during compilation:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From saving_and_restoring.py:50: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See @{tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2}.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,12], In[1]: [2794,500]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "saving_and_restoring.py", line 103, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "saving_and_restoring.py", line 89, in train_neural_network
    y: np.array(batch_y)})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,12], In[1]: [2794,500]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "saving_and_restoring.py", line 103, in <module>
    train_neural_network(x)
  File "saving_and_restoring.py", line 49, in train_neural_network
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
  File "saving_and_restoring.py", line 36, in neural_network_model
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 2122, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4279, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [32,12], In[1]: [2794,500]
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]
```

Python version is **3.6** and 
I am using **nltk** for sentimental analysis.

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
train_set_shuffled.csv shape=(2792,3)
```

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500

n_classes = 2
columns=3
batch_size = 32
total_batches = int(3000 / batch_size)
hm_epochs = 10

x = tf.placeholder( tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder( tf.float32)

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl1,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3000, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl2,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

output_layer = {'f_fum': None,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_classes])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])), }


def neural_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
    output = tf.matmul(l2, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']
    return output


saver = tf.train.Saver()
tf_log = 'tf.log'


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        try:
            epoch = int(open(tf_log, 'r').read().split('\n')[-2]) + 1
            print('STARTING:', epoch)
        except:
            epoch = 1

        while epoch <= hm_epochs:
            if epoch != 1:
                saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
            epoch_loss = 1
            with open('lexicon-2500-2638.pickle', 'rb') as f:
                lexicon = pickle.load(f)
            with open('train_set_shuffled.csv', buffering=20000, encoding='latin-1') as f:
                batch_x = []
                batch_y = []
                batches_run = 0
                for line in f:
                    label = line.split(':::')[0]
                    tweet = line.split(':::')[1]
                    current_words = word_tokenize(tweet.lower())
                    current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]

                    features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))

                    for word in current_words:
                        if word.lower() in lexicon:
                            index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                            # OR DO +=1, test both
                            features[index_value] += 1
                    line_x = list(features)
                    line_y = eval(label)
                    batch_x.append(line_x)
                    batch_y.append(line_y)
                    if len(batch_x) >= batch_size:
                        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: np.array(batch_x),
                                                                      y: np.array(batch_y)})
                        epoch_loss += c
                        batch_x = []
                        batch_y = []
                        batches_run += 1
                        print('Batch run:', batches_run, '/', total_batches, '| Epoch:', epoch, '| Batch Loss:', c, )

            saver.save(sess, "model.ckpt")
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)
            with open(tf_log, 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(epoch) + '\n')
            epoch += 1


train_neural_network(x)


def test_neural_network():
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            try:
                saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
            epoch_loss = 0

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        feature_sets = []
        labels = []
        counter = 0
        with open('processed-test-set.csv', buffering=20000) as f:
            for line in f:
                try:
                    features = list(eval(line.split('::')[0]))
                    label = list(eval(line.split('::')[1]))
                    feature_sets.append(features)
                    labels.append(label)
                    counter += 1
                except:
                    pass
        print('Tested', counter, 'samples.')
        test_x = np.array(feature_sets)
        test_y = np.array(labels)
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y}))


test_neural_network()
```

**EDIT 2**

```
feature_colum_size=12
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,feature_colum_size])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,feature_colum_size])

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl1,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_colum_size, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl2,
                  'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

output_layer = {'f_fum': None,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_classes])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])), }
```

Comment: seems your code are incomplete especailly the way you are passing the feed dict,i suspect its the way your x and y are passed, you usually have to specify the shape of the placeholder, as you declared them,it looks like there are suppose to be one single float placeholders   like this x = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32,
            shape=[batch_size,columns,
            name="images_placeholder")

Comment: Thanks, @Eliethesaiyan for your response, I have added your code now it's giving this error :           `x = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,columns, name='images_placeholder'])
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: i see, could you post the whole codes?the syntax error is because shape isn't closed tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,columns], name='images_placeholder'])

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan, I have added my code.

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan, are you there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is where you are generating your input data(batch_x). It seems that your input shape is `[batch_size,12]` that you are multiplying(matmul) your hidden layer( `hidden_layer1["weight"]`) of shape of [`3000,n_nodes_hl1`] causing the matrix mutliplication operation to fail.
and the way reading and parsing lines from train_shuffled is done makes me think that the input feature size(12) is not consistent.

What i think you should do .

Fix the input_feature size
`x = tf.placeholder('float')` to `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,feature_colum_size])`

change the  `'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3000, n_nodes_hl1]))`
to

```
'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_column_size, n_nodes_hl1])),
```

feature_column_size should be consistent between your input and the first hidden layer inorder to be able to perform matmul multiplication.

Comment: I am getting this error now after following your solution: `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 12 for 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [32,2], [32,12].`. I have updated my question with latest code.

Comment: it seems your labels have 12 classes(possible output) but want to predict only 2 classes(the possible number of outcome your model can give  is only two),you can either change the number of n_classes to 12 because you can't get your logits here cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)

Comment: since i don' t know the character of your dataset(columns and classes) and the way you are parsing them from the file, the only thing can't guide me is to know the shape of  np.array(batch_x).shape and 
                                                                      np.array(batch_y).shape

Comment: I am now getting another error `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 2) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(32, 12)'`  I am not able to understand from where this `2` is coming. I have not given `2` anywhere.

Comment: n_classes in your last hidden layer, n_classes is initialiaze to 2 , put it to a number equal to the number of classes in your label, like 12

Comment: Aaah, I see, batch_x is of shape of 32,2 in feeddict